# Retrieving Specific Active Directory Record Attributes using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've been asked to set up a process which monitors the active directory, specifically certain accounts, to check that they are not locked so that should this happen, the support team can get an early warning.

I've found some code to get me started which basically sets up requests and adds them to a notification queue. This event is then assigned to a change event and has an ObjectChangedEventArgs object passed to it.

Currently, it iterates through the attributes and writes them to a text file, as so:

```cs
private static void NotifierObjectChanged(object sender, ObjectChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ResultEntry.Attributes.AttributeNames == null)
  {
     return;
  }

  // write the data for the user to a text file...
  using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\UserDataLog.txt", true))
  {
     file.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString()
                , DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortTimeString());
     foreach(string attrib in e.ResultEntry.Attributes.AttributeNames)
     {
       foreach(object item in 
                e.ResultEntry.Attributes[attrib].GetValues(typeof(string)))
       {
            file.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", attrib, item);
       }
     }
  }
}
```

What I'd like is to check the object and if a specific field, such as name, is a specific value, then check to see if the IsAccountLocked attribute is True, otherwise skip the record and wait until the next notification comes in. I'm struggling how to access specific attributes of the ResultEntry without having to iterate through them all.

I hope this makes sense - please ask if I can provide any additional information.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

This could get gnarly depending upon your exact business requirements. If you want to talk in more detail ping me offline and I'm happy to help over email/phone/IM.

So the first thing I'd note is that depending upon what the query looks like before this, this could be quite expensive or error prone (ie missing results). This worries me somewhat as most sample code out there gets this wrong. :) How are you getting things that have changed? While this sounds simple, this is actually a somewhat tricky question in directory land, given the semantics supported by AD and the fact that it is a multi-master system where writes happen all over the place (and replicate in after the fact). 
Other variables would be things like how often you're going to run this, how large the data set could be in AD, and so on.
AD has some APIs built to help you here (the big one that comes to mind is called DirSync) but this can be somewhat complicated if you haven't used it before. This is where the "ping me offline" part comes in.

To your exact question, I'm assuming your result is actually a SearchResultEntry (if not I can revise, tell me what you have in hand). If that is the case then you'll find an Attributes field hanging off of that guy, and from there there is AttributeNames and Values. I think you'll see how it works from there if you have Values in hand, for example:

```
foreach (var attr in sre.Attributes.Values)
{
    var da = (DirectoryAttribute)attr;
    Console.WriteLine(da.Name);
    foreach (var val in da.GetValues(typeof(byte[])))
    {
        // Handle a byte[] val ...
    }
}
```

As I said, if you have something other than a SearchResultEntry in hand, let us know and I can revise the code sample.

Comment: Thank you Eric, that is very helpful.  OK, so currently the query has a scope of subtree, and I can provide you with an example query, but it currently returns all the string attributes for any user's ID that has a change applied, ie they have logged in, logged out, changed password, etc.  So what I don't want is all the data for that person, but a check to see if the person is one of a list of, in this case, service accounts, and then if yes, check to ensure that the account is not locked. An alert can be sent to the support team so that it can be unlocked as soon as someone is available.

Comment: I'd appreciate any help you can give as although i have a vague understanding of AD, it does sound like you know much more than I ever will! :)  Martin

Comment: FYI the query bein gpassed to the notifier is:    OU=Associates,OU=User Accounts,OU=XXX,OU=Migration,DC=AAA,DC=BBB,DC=CCC

Comment: Feel free to email me if we get beyond what can reasonably done on SO.

So to restrict attributes you just want to switch from asking for the * attribute set to the exact attributes you want.
That said, there is a lot of nuance in figuring out if the acct has been locked. Accounts get in to a variety of states where auth can start to fail.
To make life easier, Microsoft gave you a constructed attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677840(v=vs.85).aspx) to make life easier. Look for the lockout bit.

Comment: Thanks @Eric.  That link I'm sure will be helpful, but yes, I think I may resort to email when I get out of my depth... :)